# macros avoid space if macro expands to nothing

Tags: tables, spacing, package-writing

(preface: this lua stuff is just the motivation the real issue is with pure LaTeX)

I'm currently in some package writing in particular with LuaLaTeX. Since I'm often having a/some commands which collect some data to store data in a table to print it later (after e.g. doing some sorting or grouping). Therefore these commands just invoke `\directlua` and expand effectively to nothing.

Now when working with tables, I noticed that such commands produce extra space in a cell (even though the expand to nothing) if an optional argument is involved, see this example with some variations:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\myCmd}[2][]{}
With opt arg:\\
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
    x \\
    \myCmd{x}
    \myCmd{x}
    \myCmd{x}
    x \\
\end{tabular}
\vspace{.5cm}

\renewcommand{\myCmd}[1]{}
Without opt arg:\\
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
    x \\
    \myCmd{x}
    \myCmd{x}
    \myCmd{x}
    x \\
\end{tabular}
\vspace{.5cm}

\renewcommand{\myCmd}[2][]{}
Outside of a table with opt arg:\\
x \\
\myCmd{x}
\myCmd{x}
\myCmd{x}
x \\
\vspace{.5cm}

\renewcommand{\myCmd}[1]{}
Outside of a table without opt arg:\\
x \\
\myCmd{x}
\myCmd{x}
\myCmd{x}
x \\
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

(compiled with `pdflatex`, but `lualatex` looks almost the same)

Now I for some part I know where the spacing comes from, since when I suffix the lines just containing the `\myCmd` with a `%` (or put the lines all in one line) the space is gone.

What I definitely don't understand why this corresponds to having optional arguments.

But most importantly my question is how to get rid of the spacing (in the best case without adding something like `%` in the "normal" code since it would be nice to hide this in the implementation of my package).

Comment: A simple fix is to use `\newcommand{\myCmd}[2][]{\ignorespaces}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning of a cell spaces are gobbled using `\ignorespaces`. This is a primitive that expands tokens and discards space tokens until a nonspace token is found.

When the macro is defined without optional spaces its expansion is empty and the spaces coming from the endlines after `\myCmd{x}` are gobbled by `\ignorespaces`.

This doesn't happen when the macro is defined with an optional argument, because during expansion TeX encounters something unexpandable which does not produce text, but ends the job of `\ignorespaces` nonetheless.

If you want that a command ignores spaces (and endlines) after it, end its definition with `\ignorespaces`. But of course the best strategy is to mask the endlines you don't want to produce spaces with `%`.

Comment: So you'd suggest doing the `%` instead of using `\ignorespaces` in the end of the macro definition. Is there a particular reason for this (because having to put `%` everywhere doesn't look nice, is prone to errors and takes some effort)?

Comment: @atticus Add spaces where you want them. But you have to judge according to the particular situation. For instance, macros in `picture` mode make so that spaces are ignored.

Comment: @atticus The end-of-line becomes a "space" (=glue) because in the code file you can type three lines `text<newline>
\commandname[options]{cyx}{abc}<newline>
text`
for legibility and ease of maintenance and will be processed as one logical line. So *two* end-of-lines mark a paragraph.

Comment: Hm ok thanks so far, my issue is solved. This is just out of curiosity, why is this only an issue in the tabular environment?

Comment: @atticus Because in normal text spaces at the beginning of a line are removed in the typesetting phase. A table cell is a horizontal box, so no such removal happens, unless `\ignorespaces` has done its work previously.